How to log each virtual machine resource usage cpu time, mem etc
Running Apache with mpm_event on a shared linux server with about 5 websites (VMs)
I would like to log each VM's usage of the memory, cpu time and bandwidth for each 24hr period and have it email to me daily.
What logging app could be used to do this ?
